# Invalidate Trailing commas in Json using .NET

Tags: c#, json, validation, asp.net-web-api, json.net

How to invalidate Trailing commas in C# using Newtonsoft Json or any other opensource library

```
{
   "key": "value",  
}
```

I tried

```
JToken.Parse(jsonString);
```

But it is parsing the given request without any fail. But I want to invalidate the request in case of trailing commas. Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Why?  That's valid JSON.

Comment: @Amy as far as I know, according to specification this json is not valid, but still is accepted in many places.

Comment: @Amy please check here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. This is not valid json

Comment: Speaking of JSON.NET - you cannot easily work around this, because explicitly rejected by developer: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/818

Comment: 6 Years later i;m here looking for a workaround to this. The service that provides me the string to be parsed to json it's based on python jsons and it gives me jsons with tailing commas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works and checks for trailing commas

```
        public static bool ContainsTrailingCommas(string json)
        {
            var template = Regex.Replace(json, @"\t|\n|\r|\s+|\"".*?\""", string.Empty);
            return template.Contains(",}");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a method that checks last characters of a json string until you find a " or a '.

If you find a "," before replace it with an empty string.